# Adwords API BulkMutateJobService Fetch Global Monthly Search Volume For Multiple Keywords

Tags: search, keyword, large-data-volumes, google-ads-api

I've just gotten into the Adwords API for an upcoming project and I need something quite simple actually, but I want to go about it the most efficient way.

I need code to retrieve the Global Monthly Search Volume for multiple keywords (in the millions). After reading about BulkMutateJobService, in the Google documentation they say

> If you want to perform a very large number of operations (up to 500,000) on your AdWords campaigns and child objects, use BulkMutateJobService

But later on in the page they give limits of

> No more than 25 OperationStream objects are allowed.
>
> No more than 10,000 operations are allowed per BulkMutateRequest.
>
> No more than 100 request parts are allowed.

as well as a few others.  See source here http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/bulkjobs.html

Now, my questions:
*What do these numbers mean? If I have 1 million words I need information on, do I only need to perform 2 requests with 500K words each?*

*Also, are there examples of code that does this task?*
I only need Global Monthly Search Volume and CPC for each keyword.  I've searched online, but to no avail have I found any good example or anything leaning in that direction that utilizes BulkMutateJobService.

Any links, resources, code, advice you can offer?  All is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BulkMutateJobService only allows for mutates, or changes, to the account.  It does not provide the bulk retrieval of information.

You can fetch monthly search volume for keywords using the [TargetingIdeaService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService.html).  If you use it in STATS mode you can include up to 2500 keywords per request.

Estimates CPC values are obtained from the [TrafficEstimatorService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TrafficEstimatorService.html).  You can request up to 500 keywords per request.

FYI, there is an official [AdWords API Forum](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/forum.html) that you can ask questions on.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like I was looking at the wrong service to get my job done.  I appreciate the help.  I'll be sure to check out the Adwords Forum too!